# What will be the complexity if we want to calculate no. of digits between 1 to 10^12 whose no. of factors are exactly 4?

Tags: sieve

like for 1 to 10
no of such digits are 3.Because only 6,8 and 10 have no. of factor 4 (including 1 and the number).
We can not use SIEVE because we can not construct an array of Length 10^12.

Share your opinion...

Comment: It depends on your algorithm. You can factorize every number and then test if it has exactly 4 factors. The test for the "exactly 4 factors" is O(? + 4) because you have at most 4 elements to count.

A more efficient algorithm stops if he encounters more than 4 factors but textbook examples may not.

Comment: You write _only 6,8 and 10 have no. of factor 4 (including 1 and the number)_; what do you consider as the 4 factors of 8?